# Executing recipe with chef on Autoscaling provisioned instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, autoscaling, terraform, aws-opsworks

I have a `terraform` provisioned `AWS` structure. I have prepared chef for recipe execution but the problem is that instances don't have any `node_name` attribute cause they are being provisioned by `Terraform` using `AutoScaling Group` and `chef client` installed with `user_data` script. Node name is generated by `chef` and i need to execute some installs initially on every instance. I've tried to create `base` role and update it to server with the needed actions. Update is successful but no installs are being started on the instance. Is there any way to run a command or assign a role to every newly arrived instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers. Custom AMI is not an option so i had to research for a different approach. Turns out you can skip the `chef-service-manager` part and call `chef client` directly. Point is that you can assign `JSON` file as a parameter to `chef client`. The `JSON` can contain `runlist` and/ or `role` that can be assigned to the new instance even if it is created by `Autoscaling group`. Since i am already using `user_data` i just added the `JSON` creation in the script and assigned the needed role that already has a `runlist` in the `Chef Server`. Both answers helped me get there. Now on every new instance, via `user_data` i create a `JSON` with the role and finally i run `chef client -f role_config.json` and after that i call the service creation `chef-service-manager`. This is only a patch since the best option will be not to create it as a service but instead use `scheduled task` and call the `json` every time since if it is called for a second time for the same instance it will be disregarded in future executions. Also from what I've read in the `Chef` documentation, `scheduled task` will be a better option than using the service. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions i can think of:

1. Add the script you want to load to the EC2s in the **user_data** attribute of the [aws_instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html#user_data)

Eg:

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  ami           = "ami-408c7f28"
  instance_type = "t1.micro"
  user_data = "**your script**"
}
```

2. Launch them from your own custom AMI.

Comment: The problem of option 1 is that i don't use `aws_instance` resource. Instances are created by `launch_configuration` and `Autoscaling Group` so i cannot use `provisioner` or bind the role within the specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bake the provisioning into a mix of the AMI and the initialization script in your LaunchConfig. https://github.com/coderanger/octan_demo/blob/master/tf/octan_cluster/main.tf#L156-L167 and https://github.com/coderanger/octan_demo/blob/master/tf/octan_cluster/bootstrap.tpl is an example using chef-solo (well, local mode because solo doesn't yet support policies but that's a different story) but it should give you an idea. You would have a similar script that installs Chef, creates the config, downloads the validation key (probably from S3 using IAM roles), and then kicks off the first `chef-client` run. https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/packer/client-bootstrap.sh is another example from longer ago showing this for chef-client, in that case it was generating the config based on CloudFormation data and the Chef install + validation key were baked into the AMI.